# Как обрезать строку до последней точки

Tags: bash

Есть переменная:
`var=bla.bla.bla.com`
Как обрезать строку в переменной что бы получилось
`com` - то есть в независимости от слов и количества точек - обрезать по последней точке

```
var=bla.com     - com
var=bla.co      - co
var=bla.bla.org - org
```

Набор слов (по сути это доменные имена) может быть разным - привязываться к определенным значениям нельзя.

Пробовал:

```
var=bla.bla.bla.com
echo ${var#*.}
bla.bla.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы были в одном шаге от правильного решения.

`${var#Pattern}` удаляет самую **короткую** подстроку отвечающую образцу.

`${var##Pattern}` удаляет самую **длинную** подстроку отвечающую образцу.

> ```
> $ var=bla.bla.bla.com
> $ echo ${var#*.}
> bla.bla.com
> $ echo ${var##*.}
> com
> ```

Comment: я знал что существует вариант по утонченнее) спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

**Bash:**

```
sed -E 's|.*\.([^\.]*)$|\1|g'
```

**Example:**

```
echo qwe.rty.uio.123.456 | sed -E 's|.*\.([^\.]*)$|\1|g'
```

Comment: то что нужно - спасибо большое!